# How to solve this integral in a simple way

Tags: calculus, integration

I am working on a problem in electrodynamics and all sorts of difficult integrals pop up. In this case I am working out the electromagnetic field from a fluctuating wire current (an antenna).

$$2I_{0}\int^{h/2}_{0}\sin\left[\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\left(\frac{h}{2}-z'\right) \right]\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}z'\cos(\theta)\right)dz'=\cdots =I_{0}\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi h\cos(\theta)}{\lambda}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}\right)}{\sin^{2}(\theta)}$$

What happens at the solution step between these two expressions? I cannot understand what trick they use to get the expression on the RHS. I have tried the addition formulas, which I beleive is the key to sucess here, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: The integral is with respect to $z'$? You don't have a differential.

Comment: If you replace the integrand by a difference of sines the integral is possible, but I haven't checked out the details.

Comment: Added the differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an application of the identity $\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)=\frac 12(\sin(\alpha-\beta)+\sin(\alpha+\beta))$. When you apply it to your product of sine and cosine, you get the sum of two integrals of a sine function. The first one (the $2$ cancels) is
$$
\begin{align}
I_0&\int_0^{\frac h2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(1+\cos\theta)z'\right)\mathrm{d}z'\\
&=I_0\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(1+\cos\theta)z'\right)}{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(1+\cos\theta)}\Bigg\vert_0^{\frac h2} \\
&=I_0\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}\cos\theta\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}\right)}{2(1+\cos\theta)}
\end{align}$$
using $\int\sin(ax+b)\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\cos(ax+b)}{a}$ and similarly for the second integral, which turns out to be
$$I_0\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}\cos\theta\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{\lambda}\right)}{2(1-\cos\theta)}
$$
When you sum the two, you get your answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!